# Cognitive Services - How can I access Bing search banner information (image and birth date)

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Bing returns banner information including an image and birth date at the top of the search results when you enter a search such as 'Lady Gaga birth date'.
I would like to access this information using Microsoft Cognitive Services for an app using celebrity ages.
When I examine the httpResponseMessage return from the cognitive services call I can't find the image or birth date that appear on the top of the search results page in the body of the return.

Can you point me in the right direction to get this information from a cognitive services call.  Similarly, I'd like to be able to access the summary information that appears on the top right of the search results. Any links to advanced documentation or samples on using the cognitive services Bing web search API would also be appreciated.

Thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Those blocks are all custom. It's less about cognitive services and more about tapping into data, translating and creating a presentation.

If you go to the [Bing Web Search API site](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/bing-web-search-api/). There select "seattle seahawks" with Response Filter images. You can see that there is some text(name) and a contentUrl. You could write a parser for this to process into the pages.

Although the more logical choice would be actually calling the Bing website or Wikipedia directly. And parsing that result. As you already know it contains the information you want.

Comment: Don't forget to close the question in that case.